# Pandas: how to clip a dataframe and get the number of replaced values

Tags: python, pandas

When performing a clip operation on a dataframe...

```
df = df.clip(lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

... I'd like to get the number of elements that has been replaced, that is: the number of items below the lower_bound and above the upper_bound.

What is the most efficient way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
df_new = df.clip(lower_bound, upper_bound)

Low = (df_new>df).sum().sum()
Up = (df_new<df).sum().sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the total number of replaced values, going to NumPy domain should be efficient:

```
np.count_nonzero(clipped.to_numpy() != df.to_numpy())
```

which compares frames' underlying NumPy arrays and counts nonzeros i.e., counts `True`s to get the number of replaced values.

(if you don't want to *import* NumPy for this, an equivalent is `(clipped.to_numpy() != df.to_numpy()).sum()`.)

Answer (score 0):

An option (suggested by Ananya C.) to count the number of clipped values for a particular column (column_name):

```
num_of_clipped_values = ((df[column_name] < (lower_bound)) | (df[column_name] > (upper_bound))).sum()
```

(not tested for efficiency against other solutions)

Comment: you can accept a solution including yours to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Comment: @MustafaAydın yes... Any solution looks good to me: I would eventually accept them all.

Comment: I finally accepted @BENI's one, as it looks the most appropriate.